# Как запросить стоимость биткойна средствами JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть такая ссылка https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_rur/ticker

По ней можно узнать текущую стоимость биткойна в рублях,

```
{"ticker":{"high":28799,"low":21344,"avg":25071.5,"vol":30340589.89342,"vol_cur":1227.56161,"last":24270.059,"buy":24498.57505,"sell":24215.01,"updated":1387271282,"server_time":1387271283}}
```

У меня не получается взять по этой ссылке стоимость, на стороне браузера. 
Такой вопрос на одном сайте задавали и вроде бы даже есть решение, но оно не рабочее строка приходит, но скрипт выдает ошибку. 
Ссылка на тот вопрос https://toster.ru/q/55140

Там говорят решение

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        $.getJSON('https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_rur/ticker?callback=?').done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Но строку стоимости в браузере получить нельзя, если попытаться вывести её alert-ом то ничего не выйдет, в консоле пишет следующее

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_rur/ticker?callback=jQuery18009082755430135876_1387296762887&_=1387296763090". jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
send jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
p.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
p.(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
p.extend.getJSON jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
(anonymous function) (index):22
(anonymous function)
```

Версия jquery старее но это не причем.
Еще пишет

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :                      ticker:1
```

Помогите разобраться как мне получить и начать парсить эту строку?

Comment: Просто этот сайт имеет API, которая не предоставляет JSONP, просто возвращается JSON, который не являясь кодом JavaScript вызывает ошибку синтаксиса.  
Пишите разработчикам сайта, чтобы API реагировало на параметр callback оборачивая JSON функцией.

Comment: А что нибудь придумать, чтоб не писать разработчикам и чтоб работало? :)

Comment: Лучше напишите. Все остальное будет костылями.  
Например так: делаете запрос к своему сайту, сайт делает запрос к АПИ, результат оборачивает функцией.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

```
 public function getBitCoin()
    {
        echo file_get_contents('https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_rur/ticker?callback=?');
        exit;
    }
```

**JS**

```
  $.get('/api/getBitCoin', function (resp) {
        resp = JSON.parse(resp);
        console.log(resp);
    });
```

**JS Reponse**

```
ticker: Object
avg: 30681.09668
buy: 31014.66
high: 31110.19336
last: 30900
low: 30252
sell: 30900
server_time: 1453908548
updated: 1453908547
vol: 10000842.57298
vol_cur: 325.41815
```

Напрямую с JS - ничего не выйдет из-за Origin'а. Браузеры/Сайты не позволяют кросс-доменные запросы. По-этому данное решение представлено в примере выше.
Можно использовать и cUrl.